# json.net deserialize using linq

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I have this JSON string:

```
{
    "12":  ["game 1", 2428.8],
    "425": ["game 2",113.91],
    "40":  ["one more game name",6341.46],
    "30":  ["game name x",7535.57],
    "total": 8000.33
}
```

and I want to use json.net to parse it into an object:

```
public class Game
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: The json you have is not a deserializable as its keys are ints, and your cannot create a variable with an int representing its name, therefor you will need to manually parse it using `JObjects` Do you have access to the way the json is generated?

Comment: no I don't control it.

Comment: for field name you can easily add a prefix to all of the keys. anything starting with a letter even "Key_12", "Key_425"

Comment: The JSON is perfectly valid and it can be deserialized into a `JObject` or even a `Dictionary<string, object>`.  You do not need to prefix the keys with anything.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your JSON string using Json.Net like this:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
List<Game> games = new List<Game>();
foreach (JProperty prop in jo.Properties())
{
    if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        games.Add(new Game
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(prop.Name),
            Name = (string)prop.Value[0],
            Amount = (int)prop.Value[1]
        });
    }
}
```